# Bootstrap - Accordian: How to jump from one internal link to another?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

For a test, in the following [Bootstrap Accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_collapsible_accordion&stacked=h) example, I've created an internal link `Click <a href="#testId"` in the `Collapsible Group 1`. This internal link is supposed to jump to `<p id="testId">Jump to this element</p>` element in the `Collapsible Group 3`. But, it's not happening:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Click <a href="#testId">here</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          <p id="testId">Jump to this element</p>
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to click and go to the Collapsible Group 3 there is no need to create one more id as you already has a reference to this group.

Just reference your link to #collapse3. Find below the code snippet. I only change the:

```
<a href="#testId">here</a>
```

for:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">here</a>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Click <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">here</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          <p id="testId">Jump to this element</p>
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I had tried `<a  href="#collapse3">here</a>` but that did not work. But what you did as `<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">here</a>` worked.

Comment: nam, glad that my answer helped you. Just for your information: if you remove the `data-parent="#accordion"` the group 3 will open but the group 1 will not close. The `data-toggle="collapse"` is required is this case. Please, see this documentation for more details: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/.